# qml - Referencing top.<property> does not work from ListView?

Tags: qt, listview, qml

Can anyone tell me why the following fails?
The Rectangles specify `border.width: top.bw` where `bw` is a property in the top Window which has `id:top`.   But the result is **zero**.

If I replace `top.bw` with just `bw` it works in this demo but not in the real application which might have a `bw` defined in an intermediate object.  So I need to specify `top.bw` somehow.

What's wong with this?

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14

Window {
  id: top
  width:800; height: 800
  property double bw: 15

  ListView {
    anchors.fill:parent
    model: 3
    delegate: Rectangle {
      width: 100; height: 100
      border.width: top.bw
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand the problem you must add the following:

```
Component.onCompleted: console.log(top)
```

And you will get the following:

```
qml: QVariant(QQuickAnchorLine, )
```

So it appears that "top" is an undocumented property in [`Item`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html)(This property is for the use of anchors, for more information read [Positioning with Anchors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html)) causing a variable name conflict. The solution is to use another id like "root".

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14

Window {
    id: root
    width:800; height: 800
    property double bw: 15

    ListView {
        anchors.fill:parent
        model: 3
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 100; height: 100
            border.width: root.bw
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's documented but not well. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html `top` is an AnchorLine which are acceptable values for anchor.* settings.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess You are correct, those properties should also be noted in the "Item" docs. I will improve my response with the new information